# How to update values in map in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have map which has some keys and values and I would like to update values as listed below. 
This data is just for this testing example.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
map.put("s",100.00);
map.put("d",80.00);
map.put("a",80.00);
map.put("e",80.00);
map.put("c", 50.00);
map.put("w", 50.00);
map.put("q", 20.00);
```

After update and I print map it should give me this: 
[s=1, d=2, a=2, e=2, c=3, w=3, q=4]
Pretty much I would compare values and increments them. I case they are equal it stays the same. Map is sorted by values. 
I have stored values in list and done this in list but can not think how to do it with maps. Thank you!

Comment: The `Map` is not _sorted by values_.

Comment: so whats the actual question here? are you just asking how to do map.put("s",1) ?

Comment: I am asking how to compare these values and increment counter depending on what their value is. If they have same value, counter stays the same and is stored instead of that value.

Comment: You can see the map as the result of a game where the `"s"`, `"d"`... are players, and the map tells their scores. The result should be the positions of the players according to their scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure about what you're asking for, but perhaps it's something like this:

```
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
map.put("s",100.00);
map.put("d",80.00);
map.put("a",80.00);
map.put("e",80.00);
map.put("c", 50.00);
map.put("w", 50.00);
map.put("q", 20.00);

Map<String, Integer> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

double lastVal = -1;
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() != lastVal)
        i++;
    newMap.put(entry.getKey(), i);
    lastVal = entry.getValue();
}
System.out.println(newMap);
```

**Output:**

```
{s=1, d=2, a=2, e=2, c=3, w=3, q=4}
```

---

Here's a slightly longer, but better and more stable solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
    map.put("s",100.00);
    map.put("d",80.00);
    map.put("a",80.00);
    map.put("e",80.00);
    map.put("c", 50.00);
    map.put("w", 50.00);
    map.put("q", 20.00);

    Map<Double, List<String>> inverted = invertMap(map);
    List<Double> keys = new ArrayList<>(inverted.keySet());
    Collections.sort(keys, Comparator.reverseOrder());

    Map<String, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    int i = 1;
    for (Double key : keys) {
        for (String s : inverted.get(key))
            result.put(s, i);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

static <K, V> Map<V, List<K>> invertMap(Map<K, V> map) {
    Map<V, List<K>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (K key : map.keySet()) {
        V val = map.get(key);
        if (!result.containsKey(val))
            result.put(val, new ArrayList<>());
        result.get(val).add(key);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Go with the second solution. It doesn't rely on the insertion order of the input map.